# Using a Javascript function to change link with a button

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

I have a link that I want to change with Javascript. I've got it working but I want it to all be done on just one line. I must be writing the syntax wrong.

This is what I've got working:

```
function buttonOne(){
  window.location.href='http://www.' + brand() + '.com/';
}

<a href="javascript://" onclick="buttonOne()" class="btn btn-success">Agent Stats</a>
```

Ok and when I tried to combine them like this it didn't work:

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.' + brand() + '.com/'" class="btn btn-success">Agent Stats</a>
```

I'm sure I've just got the syntax wrong... Any ideas on how to write it so that it works fine?

Comment: what is `brand()`  and what errors do you get in the console?

Comment: brand() is just a function I've written that outputs a String variable. It's not really pertinent to this so I didn't include it.

When I pull up the console in chrome and click the link it gives me
"Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function links.html:208
onclick"

Comment: For the sake of following best practices, **don't** move your JavaScript into the `<a>`. To improve more, you could bind the `click` handler in JavaScript as well, completely separating the HTML and JS

Comment: @Ian, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by binding the click handler into the JavaScript. I'm sure it's a great idea, but if you could explain more that would be super helpful.

Comment: @mikeDvorak -- You can create a click handler for this link in your JS, that way you keep your HTML and JS separate, allowing for much cleaner code.

Comment: @mikeDvorak Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WFhrv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.  Using the exact code below works.  You'll need to provide more details on the behavior you're experiencing.  Are there any errors in the javascript console in your debugger?  Does the brand function exist and does it return anything useful?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function brand() { return 'google'; }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript://" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.' + brand() + '.com/'">Agent Stats</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: The debugger is your friend.  "Object is not a function" - referring to the anchor tag brand() function call.  This is because you have a form with the same name.  Rename the form to brand2 and it works fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/k6LFB/

Comment: The brand function does exist and returns successfully. This is the full webpage I've got up.

[pastebin.com/np8wR8ny](http://pastebin.com/np8wR8ny)